# t-sql substring

Tags: t-sql

I basically have one column that needs to be substringed. The format of the column looks as follow:

```
Column A
--------
Root\FOLDERPATH\somesubfolderpath\somedocument.doc
```

The first string "Root\" will always be the same lengt with same characters.  Everything after the "Root\" could vary in lenght depending on the document's folder structure.

What I need to retrieve is the second string. Using the above example, the column should look lilke:

```
Column A
--------
FOLDERPATH
```

So I need to cut out the "Root\" obtain the string after this and cut out everything after this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way:

```
substring(fld, 6, charindex('\', substring(fld + '\', 6, len(fld))) -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @val varchar(100)
set @val = 'Root\FOLDERPATH\somesubfolderpath\somedocument.doc'

select left(right(@val, len(@val) - 5), charindex('\', right(@val, len(@val) - 5)) - 1)
```