# how to get value from string

Tags: sql, t-sql

how to get code and sub code from query sql like this from column A with

format :

```
[very long name | code | subcode]
```

for the example

```
[Pear | S01 | 10]
[Pineapple | S01 | 9]
```

PS : there is no square brackets but the  the pipe delimiters is real

Comment: Is `[Pear | S01 | 10]` literally one field, and you need to parse it?

Comment: Yes its on one field and i need to parse it

Comment: @YanSusanto: Does the line actually contain the square brackets and the pipe delimiters, or are you just adding them for illustration?

Comment: They just Using pipe delimiters, no square .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983029/t-sql-substring, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921400/t-sql-substring-separating-first-and-last-name.  Also see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this; [DEMO - UPDATED WITH A TABLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e19d/2)

```
--declare @s varchar(50)='[Pineapple | S01 | 9]'

select substring(yourColumn,ind1 + 1,ind2-(ind1 +1)) code, 
       substring(yourColumn,ind2 + 1,len(yourColumn)-(ind2 + 1)) subcode
FROM ( 
  SELECT yourColumn, charindex('|',yourColumn,1) ind1, 
         charindex('|',yourColumn,charindex('|',yourColumn,1)+1) ind2 
  FROM yourTable
) X
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your codes are always three letters, you could use some built-in functions to help you out:

```
WITH Data(Sample) AS
(
    SELECT 'Pear | S01 | 10' UNION
    SELECT 'Pineapple | S01 | 9'
)
SELECT
    SUBSTRING([Sample], CHARINDEX(' | ', [Sample], 1) + 3, 3) AS Code,
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([Sample]), 1, 
        CHARINDEX(' | ', REVERSE([Sample]), 1) - 1)) AS SubCode
FROM
    data
```